# Why 'VarPtr' (VB6) value for a string is not the same with the value from vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I try to migrate the code from the VB6 to vb.net but i have a problem with the code from the VB6, my exactly is the part of 'StrPtr'. I search on the google and i find this code (the people say's the code is the same)

Code from VB6:

```
Dim Test_StrPtr As String
Dim Result_StrPtr As String

Test_StrPtr = "ABC ABC"

Result_StrPtr = StrPtr(Test_StrPtr)
```

The result in VB6 is: 98473644

Code in vb.net:

```
Dim Test_StrPtr As String
Test_StrPtr = "ABC ABC"

Dim handle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(Test_StrPtr, GCHandleType.Pinned)
Dim strPtr As IntPtr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject()

LBL_Test.Text = strPtr
handle.Free()
```

The value in vb.net is: 39939072

In my opinion the values can be the same, but is not. Why all people say's is the same if is not?

I try to get the same value from the vb6 is vb.net.

Comment: When you run the code twice in VB6 what happens?

Comment: Same value, i have same value every time i run.

Comment: Ohh, sorry, you right, is different, but why?

Comment: Your Result_StrPtr / StrPtr variables in both your examples are displaying the value of the memory location of the string "ABC ABC" - why would you expect these to be the same ?

Comment: In vb.net i have exactly the same value for every time I run my code. @auburg

Comment: VarPtr generates a pointer to the first element of the string.  You will **never** get a match, the runtimes of VB6 and VB.NET are drastically different and allocate memory a very different way.  VB6 does not have anything resembling a GC heap, its underlying allocator is similar to Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem().  Reference counting is used to decide when to release memory again.

Comment: Ok, i Understand, you know how is the difference between StrPtr and VarPtr and what is the difference in the code? @HansPassant

Comment: Why do you need to know the difference? Both codes find a free place in the RAM to store your string and then generates a pointer to that, which may or may not be the same (it usually isn't).

Comment: @Vladut i created the equivalent c# version of your vb.net example and the value of strPtr is (as expected) different each time i run the program. Can't see how you get the same value each time...

Comment: @auburg i try again and I stopped my program every time, the value is different, before that i try to put this code on the button and when I action him my value doesn't change. Thank you

Comment: Within a procedure the address will remain the same each time you run it within the same process because Test_StrPtr will be interned.

Comment: You program should not rely on the actual value of any pointers!